# iOS - static library framework size is very big opposed to dynamic embedded framework

Tags: ios, compilation, frameworks, static-libraries, lipo

I created a static library (framework) using the following tutorial https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework.

The size of the framework is huge - about 220 MB.

When I instead create a dynamic embedded framework , the size is only ~12MB.

Important to note that the framework is distributed as a binary.

Some of the code is written in c++ and objc++.

The linker flags in both projects are identical:

OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -l"c++"

What is causing this huge variance in size? How do I bring down the size of the static library to be the same as the embedded dynamic library?

Answer (score 0):

I feel [this blog post](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/it-looks-like-you-are-trying-to-use-a-framework/) answers this question directly (and at length). The short answer is that a static library is copied in its entirety into the binary. A dynamic framework only loads the code that is needed at load and runtime. Depending on the, well, dependencies, this could account for a huge variance indeed.